# How to assaign the return of a keywod for different variable names in robot framework?

Tags: variables, robotframework

I have created a Keyword "get information" and I want to save the return of the Keyword "get information" as a Variable. I use this Keyword multiply times and I want to save the return in different Variables.

For better understanding:

```
get information  Peter  age
return: 30

get information Maria  gender
return: female
```

I want now to create a User-Keyword "Information determination" so that I can create multiply Varaibles with different names.

I created a user-keyword with three arguements. The first argument should be the name of the variable which should be the return of the keyword "get information"

```
***Keywords***
Information determination  
   [Arguments]  ${specification}  ${name}  ${information}
   ${specification}=  get information  ${name}  ${information}

***Test Cases***
Information test
  Information determination  Peters_age  Peter  age
  Log To Console  ${Peters_age}

Output: Variable '${Peters_age}' not found.  |FAIL|
```

The return of the keyword "get information" for the arguments name and information should be saved as a variable with the name of the first argument of the user-keyword.

Another option that I tried is that I define my variables in the Variables section but it doesnt seem to work.

```
***Variables***
${Peters_age}=  get information  Peter  age

***Test Cases***
Information test
   Log To Console   ${Peters_age}

Output: get information  Peter  age
```

The return of the keyword wont save as variable but the text.

I would be pleased if someone would have a hint or a solution for my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set test variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable) to set a variable in scope for the test. The variable name itself can be composed of a variable.

Example:

```
Information determination
    [Arguments]  ${varname}  ${name}  ${information}
    ${data}=  Get information  ${name}  ${information}
    Set test variable  \${${varname}}  ${data}
```

In the above example, if `${varname}` is passed in the string `Peter_age`, then the variable `${Peter_age}` will be set for the test.